# Update data when returning from background mode in react native

Tags: react-native

Hi I'm using geolocation coordinates in react-native in order to display the users around me. I've implemented a pull-down to refresh that will let me refresh the list of users after I've changed position. How can I refresh the data when I comeback from the background mode ?

```
  displayPosition = () => {
      this.watchId = Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          let obj = {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            error: null
          }
          this.setState(obj);
        },
        (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000},
      );
      if(this.state.latitude!=null){
        this.getData();
      }else{
        setTimeout(this.displayPosition.bind(this),200)
      }
      //console.log(this.state.latitude);
      //console.log(this.state.longitude);
  }

  handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState (
      {
        refreshing: true,
      },
      () => {
        this.setState({refreshing: false});
        this.displayPosition();
        //this.getData();
      }
    );
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    this.displayPosition();
    //this.getData();
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ refresh: this._handleRefresh });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);
  }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You can add a listener for the same in react native.*

There are total 4 listners for the same.

1. **willFocus** - the screen will focus
2. **didFocus** - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
3. **willBlur** - the screen will be unfocused
4. **didBlur** - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

Try the below code

```
componentWillMount(){
    const didFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didFocus',
      payload => {
        console.warn('didFocus ', payload);
        # just write your code/call a method here which you want to execute when the app comes from background
        this.handleRefresh()
      }
    );
}
```

Dont forget to remove it when it is done.

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    didFocusSubscription.remove();
}
```

More you can read [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle). Thanks :)